# createUserWithEmailAndPassword issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am testing the createUserWithEmailAndPassword feature but It does not seem to be working.

```
private void createUserAccount() {

    String userEmail, userPassword;

    userEmail = emailRegisterEditText.getText().toString();
    userPassword = passwordRegisterEditText.getText().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterUserActivity.this, "Account created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterUserActivity.this, InstagramHomeActivity.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterUserActivity.this, "Failed to create account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have googled the issue and others have similar problems but they have a toast appear for failure. Neither a toast appears for success or failure and the ProgressDialog does not disappear for me. I am thinking that maybe it's processing or there is an error on the firebase side? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried placing breakpoints to see if the code is actually called? Also, have you enabled auth on your console?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even think to use the debugger. I placed a breakpoint on the line mAuth.createUserWithEmail and stepped over, which takes me to the line .addOnCompleteListener. Step over once again, it takes me to the ending bracket of the createUserAccount function. I am not sure what this means. If you mean the sign-in method email/password setting, then yes

Comment: I believe the problem is that onComplete is never called

Comment: Strange. Are you positive that auth is enabled Email/Password in your Firebase Console?

Comment: Yes, I am positive. I saw the deleted response and tried doing that. Nothing happens at all

Comment: Either `onComplete` is not triggered at all or it's just taking a lot of time for it to do so. It's hard to tell.

Comment: Yes, I've looked around online. It seems the emulator seems to have issues with firebase. Wish I had a physical device

Comment: @AL. if the provider isn't enabled, it would complete with an error. My first guess here would be that your device/emulator doesn't have a network connection.

Comment: I actually know the issue, and it is frustrating me to no end. The issue is incompatible google play service versions. I have the latest which is 11.0.0 which my emulator is using 10.2.98. The solutions online are confusing and I even tried the emulator with the latest API (26), which is still only 10.9...... I have tried setting the dependency to a lower version,    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.+' but this gives me errors

Comment: I've struggled with using the v11 as well when using an emulator (for some reason, an image with v11 doesn't seem available for me). When you use a lower dependency version for play services, you have to match the versions for Firebase as well.

Comment: are using 6+ characters password ? cause the minimum password length is 6 characters

Comment: Late reply but I matched the Firebase versions and it works great now. Thanks AL